# php: removing certain character Â after detecting string with space/whitespace in the front using regex

Tags: php, html, regex, whitespace, preg-match-all

I am currently trying out on a web crawler and faced this problem with regex.

The characters i want to store from the string below is "09:00 AM" :

```
<td style="border: #080707 1px solid;" lang="lang" valign="top" scope="scope"> 09:00 AM</td>
```

And below is my regex portion:

```
preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope">(.*)<\/td>/i',$link_string,$details);
```

The resulted output is Â 09:00 AM, i don' want the Â. i know that this is caused by the whitespace but i have tried a couple of different ways like:

```
    preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope">\s(.*)<\/td>/i',$link_string,$details);

    preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope">(\w+)<\/td>/i',$link_string,$details);

    preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope"> (.*)<\/td>/i',$link_string,$details);
```

However, the return is false and the characters i want is not matched.

Hope to get some enlightenment on the best way of doing this kind of regex.

Comment: it seems the whitespace is &nbsp;

so, i just include an additional metacharacter to match it as below:


preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope">(&nbsp;)?(\w+.*)<\/td>/iu',$link_string,$details);

Answer (score 0):

if you can't `trim()` the `td` tag yourself then why not use `substr()` for your output to cut the first character off:

`$time = substr($details[0][1],1) //[0][1] to be changed to actual output`

Answer (score 0):

You must just add the u modifier. With this flag the regex engine will treat your string like an unicode string. Example:

```
preg_match_all ('/<td .+ scope="scope">(.*)<\/td>/iu',$link_string,$details);
```